# Laravel Nova + Homestead SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a fresh installation of Homestead 7.17.0, Laravel 5.7.2 and Laravel Nova 1.0.14 but when I try to login with a username and password I added to the user's table, I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = user@email.com limit 1)
```

I'm sure the database configuration in my .env file is correct. Actually, I added the user via a and artisan command I've created and which prove the main app can connect to the database without problems.

Comment: Double check your port, when I used Homestead on my Mac the port was 3306 for running artisan commands but for loading the web application in a browser it needed to be 33060

Comment: You're right I put the port 33060 as the MySQL port in my config file because it's the port Homestead maps to the host machine and I wanted to run artisan commands from the host machine. But the code run from the guest machine (the app accessed from the browser, for ex.) only has access to the port 3306. What I did to solve the problem since I don't have any MySQL server instance running on my host machine and the port it's available, I've configured Homestead to map the MySQL port to 3306 on my host machine. Now I can access MySQL from host and guest machine on the same port.

Comment: Glad you solved it! I'll add it as an answer just in case someone faces the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check your port, when I used Homestead on my Mac the port was 3306 for running artisan commands but for loading the web application in a browser it needed to be 33060